# css - minumum margin between labels and their values

Tags: html, css

I need to apply a style class that will make a minumum margin to the right of labels. The tag is shown here with class "label-format":

`echo '<p><span class="label-format">Make: </span>' . $term->name . '</p>';`

`echo '<p><span class="label-format">Model: </span>' . $term->name . '</p>';`

`echo '<p><span class="label-format">Condition: </span>' . $term->name . '</p>';`

and I need to make it so that the values are pushed to the right like so (the periods represent whitespace):

Make:.........Ford

Model:........Focus

Condition:...New

the best I can get with margins is:
Make:...Ford

Model:...Focus

Condition:...New

Comment: try using a fiddle. whats the echo for?

Comment: I know its cool to hate on tables these days, but have you considered using a table?

Comment: no table needed : display or float is plenty enough to do the job

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 neither the PHP nor the HTML tag were really necessary for the question. Please try to make more meaningful suggested edits in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @Pekka웃 You're right that the PHP tag was wrong, but I think that the html tag was necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use inline-block and whidth:

```
p span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:5em; /* here set width that you want*/
}
```

`float:left;` works too :)

Answer (score 1):

A more maintainable option would simply be to use a table. For the `<td>`s containing the properties of `$term`, you could set `text-align: left;` and it will look the same.